# How to detect if a variable has not been released in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I've removed few release from my code to see if Leaks instrument in xCode can notify me about the bad code:

```
...
UINavigationController *masterNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];
UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail];
[master release];

splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNav, detailNav, nil];
//[masterNav release]; [detailNav release]; commented out
```

However I can't see any notification. Is because the memory allocated for such variables is too small ? I need a memory management tool in this phase in which I'm learning objective-C

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Product->Analyze` in Xcode4? That should show you the leak.

Answer (score 1):

Your over-retain (of detailNav) is not a leak yet, because it is still referenced by splitViewController.viewControllers. That's why Instruments won't show it as a leak.

Instruments does not flag over-retains (it can't). Only when your object is orphaned, i.e., after all other non-leaked objects have released their references, will Instruments flag it as a leak.

Answer (score 0):

go to xcode and select the project.Then click on the build and anlayze .It will gives you some  of the memory leaks